# Copy values and numberformat from one range to another?

Tags: excel, vba

I got no error with the line below where I copy the values from one range to another:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1 & ":" & "M" & lastRowOutput + 1).Value = projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").Range("B" & row & ":" & "I" & row).Value
```

But when I try to do the same with the NumberFormat I get an error message:

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1 & ":" & "M" & lastRowOutput + 1).NumberFormat = projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").Range("B" & row & ":" & "I" & row).NumberFormat
```

What I really want to achieve is to copy values from one range to another, and retain the text values as text and number values as numbers.

Comment: what error have you got?

Comment: 1004: Unable to  set the NumberFormat property of the Range class

Comment: try to use code from my asnwer

Comment: Are you using Excel 2003?

Comment: How many formats in your workbook? `NumberFormat` can trigger an error when there is more than 64000 different formats in your workbook: [excel limitations](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HA103980614.aspx)

Comment: My thought is that maybe I can't copy number format directly from a multicell range to another multicell range? When I copied number format from ONE cell to another I got no problem.

Comment: No, it works fine, try this `Range("B1:B3").NumberFormat = Range("A1:A3").NumberFormat`

Comment: Please, if you have time, take a look on: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21392069/why-error1004-unable-to-set-the-numberformat-property-of-the-range-class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").Range("B" & Row & ":" & "I" & Row).Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats
```

Comment: That works pretty well. I need to activate the output sheet before I paste to it. Ideally I would not have to activate it and ideally number formats wouldn't be copied, only whether a value is number or text.

Comment: I may have made a mistake earlier. Now it works without ativating a sheet. Thank  you! Is it possible to just copy numbers and numbers and text as text, otherwise leaving the formating alone. If I use "paste as values" Excel pastes numbers stored as text as text (as I want it to). But when I use xlPasteValues it pastes numbers stored as text as text, why? It would be great if I could avoid copying all number formating (such as whether it is a currency or not).

Comment: I really don't know what I did earlier. When I used your method it seemed to me like it copied things like "accounting" or "general". Not it doesn't any more, and that makes me happy. It only copies whether something is text or not. It works as I want it to. Unfortunately it is slower than the method I had problems with, but I can live with that.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the general idea by simply recording a macro:

```
Range("C12:C13").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("G12").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Operation:= _
    xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: Good idea, I always forget about that.