# Why Error1004: unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class?

Tags: excel, vba

Why do I get Error1004: unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class?

```
Sub ReadFile(fileName As String)
    Dim projectWb As Workbook
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim lastRowOutput As Long
    Dim row As Long

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set projectWb = Workbooks.Open(Range("folderPath") & fileName, False)

    lastRow = projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").Cells.Find("*", [A1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row

    For row = 64 To lastRow
            lastRowOutput = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Cells.Find("*", [A1], xlValues, , xlByRows, xlPrevious).row
            'The folloing line works
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1 & ":" & "M" & lastRowOutput + 1).Value = projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").Range("B" & row & ":" & "I" & row).Value 'Beställning
            'The following line generates Error1004: unable to set the NumberFormat property of the Range class?
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1 & ":" & "M" & lastRowOutput + 1).NumberFormat = projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").Range("B" & row & ":" & "I" & row).NumberFormat 'Beställning
    Next row

    'close without saving
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    projectWb.Close (False)
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: So, there is a similar [problem](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10801537/unable-to-set-the-numberformat-property-of-the-range-class). It's seems that you have too many formats on your workbook..Maximum limit of different formats is 64000. Let assume that your workbook already has 63998 different formats. If you apply `NumerFormat` to a cingle cell it may work, but when you apply `NumerFormat` to a range, limit could be exceeded.

Comment: The target workbook is an almost empty file. It has very few formats.

Comment: Try please to evaluate this line `Range("B1:B3").NumberFormat = Range("A1:A3").NumberFormat` in your destinations WB

Comment: It works; does not generate any error message.

Comment: Have you any protection in the sheet?

Comment: Thank you for investigating. I do not protect the sheet.

Comment: all formats are default or you have user defined formats?

Comment: You cannot copy formats this way in a general sense - it *can* work, but only if all cells in the source range have the same number format. Otherwise it fails silently.

Comment: Btw, try to add `projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").UnProtect` before line `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1 & ":" & "M" & lastRowOutput + 1).NumberFormat = projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").Range("B" & row & ":" & "I" & row).NumberFormat`

Comment: @TimWilliams, I've just tested it and it works for me..Aplly date format for `A2` and than call `Range("B1:B3").NumberFormat = Range("A1:A3").NumberFormat`. You will get `B1` and `B3` with general format and `B2` with date format

Comment: That was it simoco! Now it works! You're a genius!

Comment: @simoco - I set A1=number, A2=date, A3=text then tried `Range("B1:B3").NumberFormat = Range("A1:A3").NumberFormat`  That did nothing (Excel 2010, Win7): B1:B3 were all "General"

Comment: wait, it doesn't  work. I made a mistake checking and commented too early. Sorry about that!

Comment: I still get the same error message:             ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Unprotect
            projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").Unprotect
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Output").Range("F" & lastRowOutput + 1 & ":" & "M" & lastRowOutput + 1).NumberFormat = projectWb.Sheets("Beställningar").Range("B" & row & ":" & "I" & row).NumberFormat 'Beställning

Comment: Try this with mixed formats in A1:A3 - `Debug.Print Range("A1:A3").NumberFormat` - I get `Null`...  From Help for `NumberFormat`: "This property returns Null if all cells in the specified range don't have the same number format"

Comment: @TimWilliams, sorry, you're right. I've tested `.PasteSpecial xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats` and `Range("B1:B3").NumberFormat = Range("A1:A3").NumberFormat` at the same time and messed results:)

Comment: @simoco - `PasteSpecial` is the better approach here I think.

Comment: @TimWilliams, yes, but OP don't like it (follows from this [Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390958/copy-values-and-numberformat-from-one-range-to-another))

Answer (score 0):

I used the wrong language in the format:

```
,#_ ;[Rot]-#,#
```

worked for my "old" German system but not for the "new" English one.

Changing it to

```
"#,#_ ;[Red]-#,#"
```

worked.