# Can someone provide the technical reason why the `Interior.Color` property can't be assigned from one range to another in Excel VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, format

I've seen this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21390958/copy-values-and-numberformat-from-one-range-to-another) describing using the clipboard to transfer formats (and this is probably what I'll end up having to do), but I'd like to know the technical reason why values can be assigned by reference and formats can't.

In other words, why does this work...

`Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B10").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:E10").Value`

and this fail?...

`Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:B10").Interior.Color = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("D1:E10").Interior.Color`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In short, `Interior.Color` only returns *one* color, not an array of colors.

So this only works if the `Interior.Color` is the *same* for all of the source target cells.

Since `Interior.Color` doesn't return an array of differing colors, it will return `0` if the colors don't match across the source target cells.

Comment: ...and that is why all of my destination cells were black :)...Technically, my source range is an array of different values, so I was thinking that if it works for values why not for formats. Cell contents much be a lot easier for VBA to manipulate from a resource perspective. The copy/paste method is up and running and it's fine...I just try to avoid the clipboard when possible.

Comment: I agree with avoiding the clipboard where possible. Yeah, unfortunately that's the way to go with formats.