# Storing interior color from table into an array

Tags: excel, vba

I have 6 different tables Week(x) where x = a cell reference from a central run page.
Once the run button is hit I have code that clears the previous sheet and then stores the relevant week table as an array before putting those array values into the new table. Code works fine the values from the table input into the new table correctly. My question is it possible to store the Interior color of the cells in the table? I did try using RGB(x,y,z) however I believe these values need to be a constant.
I know I could just f loop into a separate array without making use of the listobject, but I'm just wondering if there's a neater way of doing it using the list object created/table.

```
  lnWeek = Cells(5, 3)
  lnTable = "" & "Week" & lnWeek & ""
  Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects(lnTable)
  laArray = tbl.DataBodyRange

  For x = LBound(laArray) To UBound(laArray)
    laArrayCol(x) = tbl.Range.Rows(x).Interior.Color
  Next x
```

Where laArray = list of names in the table _

laArrayCol = should store the interior color

`Range.Rows(x).Interior.Color` doesn't work, could I store the color of the cell in a two dimensional array along with the name of the cell or am I better off having two arrays?

Sorry if I've rambled a bit.

**Summary**

What options do you have in storing the interior color of a cell from a dynamic table?

Any help would be appreciated, sure I've made it more difficult than it has to be.

Edit: I know I could copy and paste as that would take the formatting along with it, but trying to avoid that if possible.

[image: Table with omitted info, I am trying to copy the name (x) and then the color of that name also, so it can be stored in a different table]

Comment: You're using `DataBodyRange` to create the array but `Range` to loop. `Range` includes the header row of the table. You need to be consistent.

Comment: Edit: based on your screenshot, you need to loop over each cell, and not just the rows. `.Rows(x).Interior.Color` won't work if the color varies across cells in the row, see for example [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59252780/can-someone-provide-the-technical-reason-why-the-interior-color-property-cant/59252843#59252843).

Comment: So I have changed it so the entire row has the same color, however I am still getting type mismatch?
Removed the array and changed variant>long. Now it is storing correctly, will find out if it can be transferred in a second!)

Comment: I'm not sure why you're changing the entire row to have the same color. Your screenshot clearly shows that's not the case. You'd need two loops, one for rows and one for columns. `laArray` is a 2D array.

Comment: Sorry Ben wasn't very clear, the color of the other two columns is irrelevant, it is only the color in the first column that has any value to it.

Comment: Then change `laArray = tbl.DataBodyRange` to be `laArray = tbl.ListColumns("Week").DataBodyRange.Value`, or just create a new array and then use `ReDim` to size it appropriately. Note that these are 2D arrays.

Comment: Probably should have posted the full code, I do utilize the full 3d array on the other sheet. By essentially transposing the listed table So instead of being in columns, it just runs down in rows. All of that works fine, it's just getting the color across. But as I'm writing I see what you mean, my ubound and lbound will be way off for the color! (Will change that now)